# Changing Value of XAML Color with respect to other XAML Color?

Tags: wpf, xaml, styles

I have two XAML Colors as follows.

```
<Color x:Key="DefaultColor">SteelBlue</Color>
<Color x:Key="LightDefaultColor">LightSteelBlue</Color>
```

I want to change the Color of LightDefaultColor with respect to Default Color using XAML only.

Like if i give SteelBlue, i should automatically take lighter color than SteelBlue for LightDefaultColor.

I dont want to use C# code..

`Note:` Not actually LightSteelBlue for SteelBlue but it should be lighter than SteelBlue.

Comment: So is a converter out of the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't be done in pure XAML.  You can create a ValueConverter in code that would then be applied in XAML though.

Alternatively if you really really really want 100% XAML, the best you could get would be to layer 2 elements on top of each other.  One with the base color at like 70% opactity on top of an element that's pure white at 100% opacity.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a [markup extension](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee855815.aspx) which used the default colour via `StaticResource` to return a lighter shade of it. (Regarding the XAML-only: All XAML relies on code-behind, whether it's written by you or the people developing the framework should hardly matter)